# Qt3D: Request rendering

Tags: opengl, pyside, qt3d, pyside2

My GPU used too many resources and that is why I set `QRenderSettings` to `OnDemand`. That works well when I use render my 3D scene in `Qt3DWindow`.

```py
self.renderSettings.setRenderPolicy(self.renderSettings.OnDemand)
```

But this is not the case if I render my scene in my custom `OffscreenSurface`. In an other class:

```py
self.renderCapture = Qt3DRender.QRenderCapture(
        self.offscreenFrameGraph.getRenderTargetSelector())
self.renderCapture.requestCapture()
```

Sadly `requestCapture()` does not generate an image when `OnDemand` is set on.

Comment: I'm sorry to see that you're running into so many similar issues like me that annoyed my so incredibly while working with Qt3D. I filed a bug report back then under https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66170. In my case, the CPU load was excessively high. I couldn't get the OnDemand setting to work, either. I interpreted Sean Harmer's comment that the performance issue might be related to the on demand issues, that they are aware of this problem. What Qt3D version are you using? Maybe the latest version offer some improvements.

Comment: I am glad that you filled a report. I am using version *Qt 5.11* because the this one supports _PointPicking_. However this type of picking is very slow that is why I switched to offscreen rendering.

Comment: Now it works `OnDemand´. However it does not me render last image but an image before the last.

Comment: Ah yeah, that is something I experienced as well. I triggered a second capture request at the end of the first. But this does not work well when the user can interact the the rendering process is still ongoing.

Comment: Well, now I my application changes camera properties in this `Offscreen` rendered twice. First time sets the values and then triggers a timer which sets the same properties few moments later. It works! Thanks, @Florian Blume.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I stopped using Qt3D because of its documentation and sometimes really unintuitive concepts but try to help to spare anyone the headache it has caused me :D